# How to enable Task tags (TODO,...) for java?

Tags: java, eclipse, task

I wanted to use `// TODO` tags in order to have a Task list.

I'm using Eclipse Helios, I work on a Java project, and the view I openned is "Tasks", not "Task list".
I've checked as well that there is no filter in the "Configure Contents" menu.

But the only Tasks that are listed come from HTML, or JSP files, not my Java classes !

Any ideas ?

PS: Sorry for my english, french people are definitively bad at languages !

**Edit**: When I write a `// TODO` task, the flag (the task icon) is well displayed in the left margin.
I've installed the following plugins : *M2E, PMD, Subclipse, Google plugin*, and the precise eclipse version name is  *Helios Service Release 2*, if it can help.

**Final edit** : Problem solved ! In fact a related project had build path problems. Using maven, i did not saw it ! All my apologies for such a newbie issue.
Again, thanks for all those who've tried to help me !

Comment: have tried clean and build again?

Comment: Yes, a few times : it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: There are at least two "Task tags" preference pages: one on `General|Editors|Structured Text Editor|Task tags` and the other one in `Java|Compiler'. There's another under Javascript but I don't think it's relevant. My Eclipse Helios has disabled the "struct.text" one and uses only the java one (I think!). And it works well (saving the file adds the task item).

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the preference page `Task Tags`. Is `Enable searching for Task Tags` ticked?

Comment: I'm not sure of which preference page you're speaking : There is one in the Window menu : Preferences (Java -> Compiler -> Task Tags), and another one in the Tasks view, by clicking in the down arrow.
But in thoses two cases there is no "Enable Searching for Task Tags" field.

Comment: Do you have a preference page under "Java -> Compiler -> Task Tags"?

Comment: No, there is only a page which is displaying the task tags (FIXME, TODO,...). A search of "Enable Searching for Task Tags" in the Preferences window did not match with any page.

Comment: Hmm... that is very peculiar. Which version of Eclipse are you using? *EDIT*: sorry, you already specified that: Helios...

Comment: I have been trying a couple of things, but for me, the "Tasks" view is always updated correctly with the tags specified in the Java -> Compiler -> Task Tags preference page... I don't have any further ideas right now. Sorry.

Comment: I've searched almost everywhere, with no result. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the  //TODO and perform building at least once. The task will be displayed at the task view.